# Laravel Assumes an Object and assigns an index when one record is retrieved with a wherein statement

Tags: php, laravel

I have a wherein statement for a row where I want to retrieve child rows only based on a set of foreign key employee ids. The issue is that when only one element in retrieved Laravel assumes an object and assigns an index number, this causes issues with Vue which can't find it. But when there's multiple records, Laravel makes it an array. Is there any way to force queries to be an array no matter how many rows are retrieved?

I tried toArray and still got the same result.

```
$timesheets_filtered = $jobrow->timesheets->wherein('employee_id',$employee_ids);
```

[image: single object with an index of 2]

[image]

Comment: please paste code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: where...get always returns an array. If you haven't used methods like `first()`, you should be receiving an array. You can confirm this be immediately `dd($yourQuery->get())` or through `php artisan tinker` and see for yourself.

Comment: @DanielCheung I just pasted the line I used.
$timesheets_filtered = $jobrow->timesheets->wherein('employee_id',$employee_ids);

Comment: Ok, you should specify you were asking about **Collections**. According to docs, `Collection::wherein()` returns a `Collection`. https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_whereIn This is guaranteed. So do `dd($timesheets_filtered)` immediately after that line to confirm for yourself.

Comment: I think [`->values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values) might work, otherwise you need to show some more code (how are you returning `$timesheets_filtered`, do you manipulate it first in some way etc.)